# Entity Framework 6 - Npgsql - connection string error

Tags: c#, heroku, entity-framework-6, connection-string, npgsql

A tricky (and frustrating problem) - perhaps you folks may be clever enough to solve it:

**Problem**

I want to be able to read/write to my database using Entity Frameworks. I have got a simple app rails running on Heroku (straightforward scaffold). I want to connect to this database and manipulate records. The good news is that I can successfully connect to that database using npgsql. The bad news is that I cannot do it with Entity Frameworks. This is the error I’m receiving:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error
>   occurred while getting provider information from the database. This
>   can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection
>   string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the
>   connection string is correct. --->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider
>   did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql,
>   Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k) 
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) 
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() 
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() 
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() 
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() 
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() 
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Select[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector) 
   at ge_EntityFrameworkTest.Program.<Test>d__4.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Koshy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Practice\ge-EntityFrameworkTest\ge-EntityFrameworkTest\Program.cs:line 118
```

Here is my connection string:

```
NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                sqlBuilder.Username = user;
                sqlBuilder.Password = password;
                sqlBuilder.Host = host;
                sqlBuilder.Port = Int32.Parse(port);
                sqlBuilder.Database = database;
                sqlBuilder.Pooling = true;
                sqlBuilder.UseSslStream = true;     
                sqlBuilder.SslMode = Npgsql.SslMode.Require;
                sqlBuilder.TrustServerCertificate = true;
```

Here is my “Hello world” that I am using to connect and read from my database (from the players table). It is successfully printing: “Lionel Messi” on to the console. Great!

```
            #region connectingAndReadingDatabase
            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlBuilder.ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                    // Retrieve all rows
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM players";
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
```

The problem is when I try to use Entity Frameworks. It fails massively with a painful error. I am using exactly the same connection string, and cannot for the life of me work out where I’m going wrong. Perhaps you may be able to easily spot the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Npgsql;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;


// Here is the code pertaining to my hello world entity framework example:

        [Table("players", Schema = "public")]
        public  class Player
        {
            [Key]
            [Column("id")]
            public int id { get; set; }
             [Column("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
             [Column("team")]
            public string Team { get; set; }
            public Player() { }
        }

        class NpgsqlConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration
        {
            public NpgsqlConfiguration()
            {
                SetProviderServices ("Npgsql", Npgsql.NpgsqlServices.Instance);
                SetProviderFactory ("Npgsql", Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
                SetDefaultConnectionFactory (new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory ());
            }
        }

        [DbConfigurationType(typeof(NpgsqlConfiguration))]
        public class PlayerContext : DbContext
        {     
            public PlayerContext(DbConnection connection): base(connection, true)
            {                
            }

            public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {

                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
                //modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<CascadeDeleteAttributeConvention>();
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
                modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }           
        }
```

And here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>  
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>    
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
            invariant="Npgsql"
            description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
            type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PlayerContext" connectionString="Username=hjanadgkizjmgf;Password=password;Host=ec2-54-235-250-156.compute-1.amazonaws.com;Port=5432;Database=deek4ap6cf2a1;Pooling=true;Use SSL Stream=True;SSL Mode=Require;TrustServerCertificate=True;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I pass in a connection string directly -  the same one which worked so well to retrieve records earlier, I get this curious exception:

> “Keyword not supported ‘username’” – obviously referring to the
>   connection string passed in.

```
using (var db = new PlayerContext(sqlBuilder.ToString()))
                { // etc }
```

Also curiously, I receive a warning before compiling:

> “Warning 1   Found conflicts between different versions of the same
>   dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference
>   conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
>   detailed. pg-EF-test2” perhaps it’s something to do with Npgsql?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like the "EntityFramework6.Npgsql" nuget package in the current version has incorrectly defined dependencies. It lists "Npgsql (>= 3.1.0)" as a dependency but it actually requires Npgsql in version 3.1.2 or higher.

So the fix is simple - just update the Npgsql package to the latest version. "Update-Package Npgsql" should do the trick.

And as for the context constructor with a string parameter - you got a weird exception because that constructor expects you to pass the **name** of the connection string from your config file. You should use it like this:

```
using (var db = new PlayerContext("PlayerContext"))
{ }
```

Comment: Thank you, finally found this after searching for ~1day trying to fix my multiple provider multiple context setup and actually this was my only problem. (Upgraded Npgsql from 3.1.0 to 3.2.6)

Comment: I was having this same issue and this response resolve it for me, Thanks!